# "System is out of GPU and shared host memory" when rendering

Tags: performance

Im trying to Render a simple Building with cycles. My Render settings and some statistics you can see below. Is it enough if I upgrade my RAM because my graphics card is actually very good and I don't want to buy a new one again. Or what would help here?

RTX 3070 Ti, i9-12900k 32GB 3200MHz RAM

[image]
[image]
M[image]y hardware should be able to render such simple things or not. (sorry I'm still a beginner)
[image]

Comment: You haven't asked any questions. It seems you have too much stuff in your scene for it to fit into memory. It doesn't really matter if the stuff is simple, there is too much of it.

Comment: @MartynasŽiemys do you think upgrading to 64gb ram would help? Also, I just found out that my CPU can do the rendering, but it takes a while.

Comment: @user148905 Have you tried restarting your computer? Then open Blender and do a render. It works for me when it happens during projects. Also, can you share your .blend file? It would probably help to check what is the problem.

Comment: Also, try enabling spatial splits if it doesn't work after the restart. What resolution textures are you using?  Sharing the .blend file will help us find the solution

Answer (score 1):

Which version of Blender are you using? Get the 3.2 Beta if you don't have it and use the render noise threshold set to .1 or .2

Often having the CPU enabled as a rendering device will actually slow it down. Test it yourself to see in your scenario.

Check the size of your textures. You should be using 1-4K texture maps for the majority of materials unless you're really close to the object. Same for the world shader.

Use optix denoising for viewport, and OIDN for rendering. (low/fast vs high/slow 0quality denoising)

Set render feature set to experimental and try adaptive subdivision. Is your subdiv/displacement optimized?

What are your light paths in the render properties set to? Press delete on all of them to set them to default.

Is your grass scattering optimized/instanced properly?

Disable objects or groups of objects and see what provides the most performance gain when disabled.

It looks like your geometry count is low for your hardware spec so I'm gonna geuss it's your texture size. Increasing your ram wont help much, the problem is your GPUs VRAM.Wait till next gen(hopefully mid July) and get one with more than 8GB.

Before trying to render leave material preview shading(wireframe ideally) and then render. This way more memory isn't held up from material preview mode when it wants to access it for rendering.

Your hardware is more than capable. You should also get the latest Nvidia Studio driver.